# Is $S^3\times S^2$ orientable?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

The question comes from another question, I am asked to calculate the dimension and check orientability of the manifold

$$ V_2(\mathbb{R}^4) = \{(v_1,v_2) \in \mathbb{R}^4\times \mathbb{R^4} \mid |v_1|=|v_2|=1, v_1\cdot v_2=0\} $$

And I prove via the projection $\pi(v_1,v_2)=v_1$ that $V_2(\mathbb{R}^4)=S^3\times S^2$ ($\text{Im}(\pi) = S^3$ and $\forall x\in S^3, \pi^{-1}(x)=S^2$). Following that, the dimension is $5$ but what about orientability?

Comment: Just to check - it is true that $V_2 (\mathbb{R}^4) \simeq \mathbb{S}_3 \times \mathbb{S}_2)$, but the proof is somewhat more involved than what you wrote (for instance, if you replace $\mathbb{R}^4$ by $\mathbb{R}^3$, the similar statement $V_2 (\mathbb{R}^3) \simeq \mathbb{S}_2 \times \mathbb{S}_1$ is false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S^3\times S^2$ is orientable since both manifolds are orientable, just take the product of the orientations. But what you showed is that $V_2(\mathbb R^4)$ is an $S^2$ bundle over $S^3$, you want to say that it is the trivial bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how I could show that it is the trivial bundle to complete my proof? A reference is fine too.

Comment: You need to look at the clutching function and see if it is orientation preserving or not (decompose $S^3$ as a union of two 3-balls, on each of those the bundle is trivial).

Comment: Also it isn't too hard to show that in fact every $S^k$ (say for $k\geq 1$) bundle over $S^n$ (for $n\geq 2$) is orientable as a bundle. This just comes from noting that the so called clutching function must have image entirely inside one component of the structure group (in this case $\operatorname{Homeo}(S^k)$) as $S^{n-1}$ is connected.